# Notation for proof with Tensors

Tags: notation, tensors

I'm working on proving

> For a second order tensor $\mathbf{A}$,$\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{u}=0$ for all vectors $\mathbf{u}$ if and only if $\mathbf{A}$ is skew symmetric.

Now, I understand the proof for it fully. But I came up with (what I think) is a clever way to do it. The notation of what I did is what I'm having trouble with.

For the direction that $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{u}=0 \implies \mathbf{A}$ is skew symmetric, I defined vectors $\mathbf{u}^{(r,s)}$. Where the vectors defined in indicial notation are $u_i^{(r,s)}=\delta_{ri}+\delta_{si}$.

Some examples of my vector in three dimensions are
$$\mathbf{u}^{(1,1)}=[2,0,0]$$
$$\mathbf{u}^{(2,3)}=[0,1,1]$$

Now, the superscript parenthesis is my own notation. $r$ and $s$ are supposed to be fixed as a free index. And I'm interested, first, in the case where $r=s$. So basically,

$$\mathbf{u}^{(r,r)}\cdot\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{u}^{(r,r)}=A_{ij}u_i^{(r,r)}u_j^{(r,r)}=A_{ij}(2\delta_{ri})(2\delta_{rj})=4A_{rr}=0$$

I want this to show that the element in column $r$ and row $r$ is zero if we used the matrix representation.

But this makes it seem like it's now a dummy variable and that we are summing over all possible values of $r$.

What did I do wrong or is there a better way to notate what I wanted to?

Also, we are using the book "The Linearized Theory of Elasticty" by William Slaughter. The indicial notation is all subscripted (unlike conventional Einstein indicial notation which has both subscripts and superscripts)

After discussion with Avitus, i believe my question boils down more to:

> "How do I represent the particular elements $A_{11},A_{22},\cdots$ in the indicial notation without making $i$ in $A_{ii}$ a dummy variable? And how do I pick my notation for $\mathbf{u}$ accordingly?"

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy is correct: you probably need to change notation a bit. I suppose you want to prove

$$I:=\sum_{k,l=1}^n u_k A_{kl} u_l = 0~~\forall u\in\mathbb R^n \Rightarrow A_{kk}=0,~A_{kl}=-A_{lk},~~ k\neq l. $$

To prove the first skewness relation for $A$ we choose $u=(0,\cdots,1,\cdots,0)$, where the $1$ corresponds to the $i$-th coordinate, i.e. $u_k = \delta_{ik}$, $k=1,\dots,n$. Then

$$I=A_{ii}=0.$$

Repeating the same argument for all $i=1,\dots, n$ one arrives at  the first skewness relation for $A$.

We are left to prove that $A_{ij}=-A_{ji},~~ i\neq j$. In this case we choose $u=(0,\cdots,1,\cdots,1,\cdots,0)$ where the $1$'s correspond to the $i$-th and $j$-th coordinate, with $i\neq j$. Then then sum $I$ consists of 2 terms: in the first one $i=k$ and $l=j$; in the second $k=j$ and $l=i$, leading to

$$I= A_{ij}+ A_{ji}=0.$$

Choosing all possible distinct pairs $i,j=1,\dots,n$ leads to the second skewness relation for $A$.

Comment: Thank you for showing the proof in a different notation. But, unfortunately, I didn't have a question about how to prove it. I'm just having notation issues in the indicial notation. Because in the notation, $A_{ii}=0$ is identical to $\sum_{i=1}^nA_{ii}=0$ which is not that same as $A_{11}=A_{22}=A_{33}=\cdots=0$. I suppose a more concise question would be: "How do I represent the particular elements $A_{11},A_{22},\cdots$ in the indicial notation without making $i$ in $A_{ii}$ a dummy variable."

Comment: I would avoid the notation $A_{ii}=\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ii}$: it can generate confusion. In this case one can simply try to be coherent with the usual notation for matrix elements: if $M$ is a matrix, then $M_{ii}$ denotes the $i$-th diagonal element and not the trace of the matrix itself.

Comment: I cannot avoid the notation $A_{ii}=\sum_{i=1}^nA_{ii}$ because that is the tensors index notation convention in this book.

Comment: This is fine: once it is clear what $A_{ii}$ means, then all follows. As said, for coherence, for example, with matrix notation, I would avoid to denote summation in cases like $A_{ii}$. Is the book clear about this passage? Is there something like "a notation" section?

Comment: Yes, there is a section: Most notably "If an index appears twice in a term of an indicial notation equation, summation over the range of the index is implied. Such an index is called a dummy index." It's essentially [Einstein notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation#Statement_of_convention).

Comment: Ok, then all boils down to the noun "term": if term is a product of mathematical objects with indices, then we agree on notation: for example $f_{ij}g^{jk}$ means  $\sum_{k}f_{ij}g^{jk}:=\Gamma_i^k$. Also the wiki page on EInstein notation gives only examples of products. In absence of products I would avoid summation.

Comment: I would agree with you (if you mean that we sum over $j$ and not $k$), except the book gives this example: $g_{iji}=k_j$ is the same as these three equations: $g_{111}+g_{212}+g_{313}=k_1$, $g_{121}+g_{222}+g_{323}=k_2$, $g_{131}+g_{232}+g_{333}=k_3$. It mixes free and dummy indices, but the concept that there is no multiplication on the left side and we still use the summation convention is clear. And elsewhere: $a_{pp}=B_pc_p\iff a_{11}+a_{22}+a_{33}=B_1c_1+B_2c_2+B_3c_3$

Comment: Personally I find such notation confusing. In any case, the equality $\sum_{ij}A_{ij}\delta_{ir}\delta_{jr}=A_{rr}$ you wrote in the OP has to be meant without the summation index on the right hand side, even if you have 2 indices with the same "name" because you selected a choice for $r$. What is important is that all follows is coherent with it. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping me clarify exactly where I was having trouble. I'm going to leave the answer unaccepted in hopes that there is a way to do it under the summation convention. Thank you again, though.

Comment: You are welcome. However, I cannot see why you want to reconciliate $\sum_{ij}A_{ij}\delta_{ir}\delta_{jr}=A_{rr}:=A_{11}+\dots+A_{nn}$ as the second equality is simply wrong, for any fixed $r$. Just define "dummy variables summation" for products and leave diagonal elements unsummed. I do not see alternatives (to finish my considerations: how does the author define the $i$-th diagonal element $A_{ii}$ in his book, if he automatically assumes summation in presence of repeated indices?)